# How I can create file on Xamarin.ios (PHP Session)

Tags: c#, php, file, xamarin, xamarin.ios

i need to create a (.txt) file on my application root on Xamarin.ios, so a need to store in memory a String, contain a UserName, after the user logged in, I can use each String to run a "httprequest" to my mySql database online. Similar procedure to the sessions in PHP, but client side and in C#.. Thanks you. I just try, with cookie, but I need to access at the UserName in every class and in every storyBoard.

I just try to write a JSON file serializable:

```
String NU = "NomeUtente=" + NomeUtente.Text;
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(NU, Formatting.Indented);
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"/558gt.txt", json);
```

but Xamarin.ios throw a exception:

> SystemUnauthorizedAccessexception -->
>   access to the path /558gt.txt denied.

Comment: Why do you think you can write a file to root `/`?

Comment: how I can do it? the file must be reachable also when the Application run in iOS.

Comment: Actually, the mine file it should stored in the application root.

Comment: Well then you should probably try figure out how to get the correct path to save the file in App root. Using `/` is wrong. Take a look at the `Environment` static.

Comment: I would try System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"./558gt.txt", json);  Notice the dot before your slash this drops you into the path of your application executable which is something you might have access.  Root level access is not going to work on iOS.

Comment: In the last case, Xamarin don't throw exceptions, but I don't find the file, and I can't open it. Maybe I use iOS debugging and emulation.. is correct?

Comment: iOS app bundles are signed and therefore not writable.  Please take the time to read the relevant docs about using the iOS filesystem.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/file-system here is infomration regarding file and folder access looks like you can use the Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments to write files.

Comment: Thanks you all. 
I solved and will move the code, I read how to use the iOS stistem file, so it is possible to create files, read them directly from the application sandbox.

Answer (score 0):

If you need store data, use `Xamarin.Essentials.SecureStorage`

[Check documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/xamarin/essentials/secure-storage?context=xamarin%2Fandroid&tabs=ios)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you. I read the documents on the ios file system and managed to write the portion of code necessary for reading and writing the Session file containing the username.

```
 try {
      //creo il file nella sandbox maledetta di iOS
      //create file Session
      var documents = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
      var filename = Path.Combine(documents, "Session.txt"); 
      //filename contiene la path completa di dove sta il file  
      File.WriteAllText(filename, NomeUtente.Text);

      }
      catch (Exception) {
           label1.Text = "Errore generico.";
      }
```

and now I read the file, in a separated class and storyboard:

```
//Recupero il nomeutente
var documents = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
var filename = Path.Combine(documents, "Session.txt");
var NomeUtente = File.ReadAllText(filename); //contiene il NomeUtente
```